# Launch Program "<.exe program path>" does not exist. C++ debugging Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

[image]
When i press debug, i always get this error. The program does not exist.

[image]
I have configured the launch.json file looking at different guides but still havent gotten rid of this issue.

Comment: if you don't compile your program there will be no `assignment1.exe`, your source file is named `assignment_1.cpp` and it looks like you try to compile `new.cpp`

Comment: @riov8 i have compiled my assignment_1.cpp file and still am getting the same problem. and what do you mean im compiling new.cpp

Comment: the first image has this in the terminal: `g++ -g new.cpp`, and what is the task `echo`?